# Localization arguments in the paper 'the proof of $l^2$ decoupling conjecture'

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am currently reading Jean Bourgain and Ciprian Demeter's 2015 paper *The proof of the $l^2$ decoupling conjecture* and would appreciate some help in understanding localization argument used in that article.

There are some definitions. Let $P^{n-1}$ be the truncated paraboloid. More precisely,
$$P^{n-1}=\{(\xi_{1},...,\xi_{n-1},\xi_{1}^2+...+\xi_{n-1}^2)\in \mathbb{R} : |\xi_{i}| \leq \frac{1}{2}\}$$
Let $N_{\delta}$ be the $\delta$ neighborhood of $P^{n-1}$, and let $P_{\delta}$ be a finitely overlapping cover of $N_{\delta}$ with curved regions $\theta$ of the form
$$\theta = \{(\xi_{1},...,\xi_{n-1},\eta + \xi_{1}^2+...+\xi_{n-1}^2) : (\xi_{1},...\xi_{n-1}) \in C_{\theta}, \; |\eta| \leq 2\delta   \}$$
where $C_{\theta}$ runs over all cubes $c+[-\frac{\delta^{1/2}}{2},\frac{\delta^{1/2}}{2}]^{n-1}$ with 
$$c \in \frac{\delta^{1/2}}{2}\mathbb{Z}^{n-1} \cap [-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]^{n-1}$$
For a cap $\tau$ on $P^{n-1}$, we let $g_{\tau}=g1_{\tau}$ be the (spatial) restriction of $g$ to $\tau$. Let $w_{B_{R}}(x)$ be weight function such that it is Fourier supported in $B(0,\frac{1}{R})$ and satisfy
$$1_{B_{R}}(x) \leq Cw_{B_{R}}(x) \leq C'(1+\frac{|x-c(B_{R})|}{R})^{-10n}$$

The key definitions are followings. 
Let $K^{(1)}_{p,n}(\delta)$ be the smallest constant such that
$$||\widehat{gd\sigma}||_{L^p(w_{B_{\delta^{-1}}})} \leq K^{(1)}_{p,n}(\delta)(\sum_{\theta : \delta^{1/2}-\mathbb{cap}}||\widehat{g_{\theta}d\sigma}||_{L^p(w_{B_{\delta^{-1}}})}^2)^{1/2}$$
for each $g : P^{n-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and each $\delta^{-1}$ ball $B_{\delta^{-1}}$.

Let $K^{(2)}_{p,n}(\delta)$ be the smallest constant such that
$$||f||_{L^p} \leq K^{(2)}_{p,n}(\delta)(\sum_{\theta \in P_{\delta}}||f_{\theta}||_{L^p}^2)^{1/2}$$

for each $f$ Fourier supported in $N_{\delta}$ and each $\delta^{-1}$ ball $B_{\delta^{-1}}$. Here, $f_{\theta}$ denote the Fourier restriction of $f$ to $\theta$.
Now, Bourgain says that

> $$C_{p,n}^{-1}K^{(2)}_{p,n}(\delta) \leq K^{(1)}_{p,n} \leq C_{p,n}K^{(2)}_{p,n} $$

It is written at remark 5.2. He did not write the proof but say that the following simple observation justifies the various (entirely routine) localization arguments :
If $g$ is supported on $P^{n-1}$ and if $\widehat{w_{B_{R}}}$ is supported in $B(0,R^{-1})$, then $\widehat{(gd\sigma)}w_{B_{R}}$ has Fourier support inside $N_{R^{-1}}$.

I showed right inequality. I got some hints from the Wolff's 2000 paper  *Local smoothing type estimates on L^p for large $p$*.

The proof of $K^{(1)}_{p,n} \leq C_{p,n}K^{(2)}_{p,n} $ :

Write $f(x)=\widehat{gd\sigma}(x)w_{B_{\delta^{-1}}}(x)$. By the Bourgain's observation,
\begin{equation}
||\widehat{gd\sigma}||_{L^p(w_{B_{\delta^{-1}}})} =||f||_{L^p} \leq K^{(2)}(\sum_{\theta \in P_{\delta}}||\Theta_{\theta} \ast (\widehat{gd\sigma}w_{B_{\delta^{-1}}})||_{p}^2)^{1/2}=K^{(2)}(\sum_{\theta \in P_{\delta}}||\sum_{\phi}\Theta_{\theta} \ast (\widehat{g_{\phi}d\sigma}w_{B_{\delta^{-1}}})||_{p}^2)^{1/2} \leq K^{(2)}(\sum_{\theta \in P_{\delta}}\sum_{\phi \in J(\theta)}||\Theta_{\theta} \ast (\widehat{g_{\phi}d\sigma}w_{B_{\delta^{-1}}})||_{p}^2)^{1/2} \leq K^{(2)}(\sum_{\phi : \delta^{1/2}-cap}\sum_{\theta \in J(\phi)}||\Theta_{\theta} \ast (\widehat{g_{\phi}d\sigma}w_{B_{\delta^{-1}}})||_{p}^2)^{1/2} \leq K^{(2)}(\sum_{\phi : \delta^{1/2}-cap}||\widehat{gd\sigma}w_{B_{\delta^{-1}}}||_{p}^2)^{1/2} = K^{(2)}(\sum_{\phi : \delta^{1/2}-cap}||\widehat{g_{\theta}d\sigma}||_{L^p(w_{B_{\delta^{-1}}})}^2)^{1/2}
\end{equation} 
Here, $\Theta_{\theta}(x) = \widehat{1_{\theta}}(-x)$ and $J(\theta)=\{\phi : \Theta_{\theta} \ast (\widehat{g_{\phi}d\sigma}w_{B_{\delta^{-1}}}) \neq 0\}$. I used the fact that the cardinality of $J(\theta)$ is uniformly bounded for $\theta$.

I tried to show that $K^{(2)} \leq CK^{(1)}$ but it is extremely hard to me. Any hint or reference are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems similar to Problem 2.2 of my lecture notes http://de.arxiv.org/pdf/math/0311181.pdf .  I think one should first convolve $f$ by some suitable approximation to the identity $\varphi$ Fourier concentrated near $B_{\delta^{-1}}$, then disintegrate $\hat f*\varphi$ into measures $g_t\ d\sigma_t = \sum_\theta g_{t,\theta}\ d\sigma_t$) supported on vertical translates $P^{n-1}+te_n$ of the paraboloid $P^{n-1}$, apply the $K^{(1)}$ bound, then use something like Schur's test to control the $L^p$ norm of $\widehat{g_{t,\theta}\ d\sigma_t}$ by that of $f_\theta$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But how to control the $l^2$ norm of $L^{p}$ norm of $g_{t,\theta}d\sigma_{t}$ via that of $f_{\theta}$? That is the most difficult part. In Problem 2.2, this part can be easily resolved. How to use Schur's test? How to take integral operator?

Comment: I think $\widehat{g_{t,\theta} d\sigma_t}$ is just the convolution of $f_\theta$ with $\widehat{d\sigma_t}$, so one basically just needs to estimate $\widehat{d\sigma_t}$ on $B_{\delta^{-1}}$ (it should be concentrated on the dual $\delta^{-1/2} \times \delta^{-1}$ tube).

Comment: I completely understand what you say! Your comments are of great service to me. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Brian: Would you please elaborate on how you obtain the inequality

$$K^{(2)}(\sum_{\phi : \delta^{1/2}-cap}\sum_{\theta \in J(\phi)}||\Theta_{\theta} \ast (\widehat{g_{\phi}d\sigma}w_{B_{\delta^{-1}}})||_{p}^2)^{1/2} \leq K^{(2)}(\sum_{\phi : \delta^{1/2}-cap}||\widehat{g_{\phi}d\sigma}w_{B_{\delta^{-1}}}||_{p}^2)^{1/2}$$

It seems that like you're using Young's inequality and Holder's inequality together with the uniform boundedness of $J(\phi)$. If so, in your application of Young's inequality, how do you know that $\|\Theta_{\theta}\|_{1}$ is finite?